# Background size has cut off some part when the screen reduce size

Tags: css, html, layout, background

[image]

Here is the test link:

http://kotechweb.com/ig112/

The problem is , I found that when I reduce the window screen,  the background width is only the size of the window, when I scroll it , the other part cut off the background.

The code:

```
<div style="background:url('./assets/image/bg4.jpg'); padding-top:20px;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        ....                    
                    </div>    
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>
```

Also , one background have customized the CSS like this:

```
background: url('./image/bg1.jpg') top;
padding: 20px 0px;
background-position: 0px -20px;
background-size: 100% 99%;
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Please Give background-size:cover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the horizontal scrolling isn't something you want, because you're including the Bootstrap library.

In your style.css you have overwritten the default .container size which is breaking the responsiveness of the page:

```
.container {
    width:960px !important;
}
```

If you remove this, your page will become responsive with one exception.

Your .top_btn class has a position of absolute. This isn't great for responsive because it's pushing these elements outside of your body. You could continue having these as position:absolute if your left and top properties are percentages. Or instead slice the image that these are over into 3 difference images and have them link separately instead of absolutely positioning images over the one image.